Merge into using pyspark databricks
Can someone please help me with below problem. I need to perform merge operation in databricks,
I need help in handling deletes('D'). Here is the update (Source) table.
update_data = [(i, f'updatedFirstName{i}', 50000 + i * 1000) for i in range(1, 10)]
update_columns = ["id", "firstName", "salary"]
df_updates = spark.createDataFrame(update_data, update_columns)


Assume here is my target delta table,
data = [(i, f'firstName{i}', 'I', 40000 + i * 500) for i in range(1, 201)]
columns = ["id", "firstName", "Crud", "salary"]
df_tgt = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)


I get keys that should be marked as 'D' as dataframe, and I collect using
del_keys = [row.id for row in df_del_keys.collect()]

let's assume, deleted keys with id values are 101 and 102 should be marked as 'D' in target. Deleted keys(101 and 102) won't be available in updates(src) table, for sure.
What I tried?
mergeCondition = " AND ".join([f"tgt.{field} = src.{field}" for field in ["id"]])
updateCondition = f'tgt.{salary} != src.{salary}'
columnsList = ['firstName','salary']
updateValues = {"tgt." + field: col("src." + field) for field in columnsList}
updateValues.update({"tgt.Crud": lit('U')})
del_keys = [row.id for row in df_del_keys.collect()]
(
    deltaTablePeople.alias('tgt')
    .merge(deltaTablePeopleUpdates.alias('src'), mergeCondition)
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        condition=updateCondition,
        set=updateValues)
    .whenNotMatchedBySourceUpdate(
        condition=f"id IN ({', '.join(map(int, del_keys))})",
        set={"Crud": lit('D')})
 .execute()
)

This is working, but if I get many del_keys(may be in thousands), driver node isn't capable of keeping them. So, I tried as below.
mergeCondition = " AND ".join([f"tgt.{field} = src.{field}" for field in ["id"]])
updateCondition = f'tgt.{salary} != src.{salary}'
columnsList = ['firstName','salary']
updateValues = {"tgt." + field: col("src." + field) for field in columnsList}
updateValues.update({"tgt.Crud": lit('U')})

del_keys=[101,102]
df_del_keys.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_del_keys")

(
    deltaTablePeople.alias('tgt')
    .merge(deltaTablePeopleUpdates.alias('src'), mergeCondition)
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        condition=updateCondition,
        set=updateValues)
    .whenNotMatchedBySourceUpdate(
        condition="id IN (select id from temp_del_keys)",
        set={"Crud": lit('D')})
 .execute()
)

Looks this isn't supported in databricks. Can some one please help me how to handle deletes(del_keys)?
I expect target table as below after the merge, and I wanted to achieve this using one merge operation.

values for Salary attribute for id 11,12,101, and 102, will be as in target.
Crud for id 11 and 12, won't change, because 11 and 12 isn't available in update (source) table. But Crud for 101, 102 should update as D, because they are to be marked as deleted.

Are you trying to update the Crud column in the target table to 'D' for all values in the del_key list?  And update the rows which are present in both target and source dataframes? Maybe if you update the question with what you are expecting your final output to look like, it would help us understand the question better

Yes, update only in target! let me update expected output too!

@AnupamChand Updated the expected output.

IIUC, you can run the merge twice in this case, where

First merge, just perform all your inserts and updates using your updates dataframe
Second merge will update the crud to ’D’ based on your deleted dataframe.

Ex:
First Merge will be like
mergeCondition = " AND ".join([f"tgt.{field} = src.{field}" for field in ["id"]])
updateCondition = f'tgt.{salary} != src.{salary}'
columnsList = ['firstName','salary']
updateValues = {"tgt." + field: col("src." + field) for field in columnsList}
updateValues.update({"tgt.Crud": lit('U')})
del_keys = [row.id for row in df_del_keys.collect()]
(
    deltaTablePeople.alias('tgt')
    .merge(deltaTablePeopleUpdates.alias('src'), mergeCondition)
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        condition=updateCondition,
        set=updateValues)
 .execute()
)

Second Merge will be:
deleted_df = df_del_keys.select('id').distinct()

mergeCondition = " AND ".join([f"tgt.{field} = src.{field}" for field in ["id"]])

(
    deltaTablePeople.alias('tgt')
    .merge(deleted_df.alias('src'), mergeCondition)
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        set=={"Crud": lit('D')})
 .execute()
)

This way you can easily update the deleted ID's as D and no data is collected on the driver

Can this be done in single merge?

can be done then you need to combine your updates dataframe with deletes dataframe and add another condition.

Can you give how to achieve in single merge?

Since you have 2 input reference tables, you need to do some kind of union to use the merge statement if you want to avoid using 2 Merge statements.
First create the target tables and the 2 input views.
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
update_data = [(i, f'updatedFirstName{i}', 50000 + i * 1000) for i in range(1, 7)]
update_columns = ["id", "firstName", "salary"]
df_updates = spark.createDataFrame(update_data, update_columns)
df_updates.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_update")


data = [(i, f'firstName{i}', 'I', 40000 + i * 500) for i in range(1, 12)]
columns = ["id", "firstName", "Crud", "salary"]
df_tgt = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df_tgt.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("target_tbl")

df_del_keys = spark.createDataFrame([10,11], IntegerType())
df_del_keys.show(truncate=False)
df_del_keys.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_del_keys")

Now use 1 merge statement. I will use databricks SQL but you can convert this to normal pyspark using
spark.sql("<databricks sql statement?")

Note the union i've done between the vw_update and vw_del_keys. The when not matched condition is present incase you would like to insert new entries via the vw_update view itself. If not, you can remove it however there is no harm in keeping it.
%sql
MERGE INTO target_tbl
USING (SELECT * from vw_update UNION SELECT value as id, null as firstName, -1 as salary FROM vw_del_keys) as A
ON (A.id = target_tbl.id)
WHEN MATCHED AND A.salary > -1 THEN
  UPDATE SET
    crud = "U",
    salary = A.salary,
    firstName = A.firstName
WHEN MATCHED AND A.salary = -1 THEN
  UPDATE SET
    crud = "D"
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (
    id,
    firstName,
    salary,
    crud
  )
  VALUES (
    A.id,
    A.firstName,
    A.salary,
    "I"
  );

SELECT * FROM target_tbl;

Your target table will now be.

